# access denied when mysql to localhost using public ip

Tags: mysql, authorization

I would like to use the command below to connect to my Mac's local database (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the Mac's ip address)

```
mysql -u cgao -h xx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p
```

and I got the error message:

```
ERROR 1045 (20000): Access denied for user 'cage'@'dhcp-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.dyn.mycompany.com' (using password: YES)
```

But it will succeed when I enter the same command in another computer. How can I solve it? Can I only use localhost or 127.0.0.1 to local machine?

I feel it is somehow related to the dynamic ip address in my company. But I didn't find the exact answer on the web. Can someone elaborate the reason and share suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to login to MySQL on the local machine using the IP address do this

```
mysql -u cgao -h xx.xxx.xxx.xxx -P3306 --protocol=tcp -p
```

This force a TCP/IP connection locally

Comment: Thanks @RolandoMySQLDBA . Does this have any speed issue?